# HTML displays different on different mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have the problem that my email template is displayed differently on different mobile devices.
The textbox is sometimes centered, but should always be left aligned.

Does anyone have an idea what this could be and how I can solve the problem?

How it should be on every devise:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FuXJ.png)

How it it (sometimes):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kRN1.png)

Comment: You can check with the browser dev-tools how the page looks like on different devices / screen sizes.

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about providing a [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try to use a media-query at the specific resolutions that look different and apply different css rules to ensure it stays left aligned. e.g.

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .cssClass {

  }
}
```

As for the reason, some screens have different pixel ratios, and therefore the padding or other values sometimes change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your style.css file:

```
    .yourClass{
        justify-content:start;
     }
```

Have a nice day,
Angélique.